# Dll and exe in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

i have a doubt when we run the application (dot net application) dll or exe will be created yes. so my question is when we get dll when we get dll and when we get exe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will create a dll (which contains the backend code) and aspx/asmx/as** files which contain your frontend code (markup and stuff like that).

You will NEVER get an exe (that is for executable applications like Winforms and WPF apps).

Comment: ok in webapplication we get dll and in winforms we get exe am i right Mr.Snake (intresting name)

Comment: You are right. But class libraries (which both work in WebApp and Winforms) also produce dlls :)

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the Web Project in your solution and select `Publish`. This will build your web application to a location, and you will get the site structure of .aspx files, and a folder `bin` containing the .dll files of your code.

See here for more info: [How to: Publish Web Application Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983453%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: ya i did like that i get what i want thank you Mr. Codesleuth

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand your question, could you explain more clearly please?

I suppose that you mean you want to know when you have to use EXE or DLL, well, if you have to develop a desktop application, you have to use EXE, but if you do a web application, only DLL linked to ASP.

Greettings.